# Rolling log4j file to specific name

Tags: java, log4j

On a special application event I need to roll log file and rename to specific file name that contains date and time.

This is function I use to roll file:

```
public void rollOver()
    {
        Enumeration el=  Logger.getRootLogger().getAllAppenders();

        while ( el.hasMoreElements() ) 
        {
            Appender a = (Appender) el.nextElement();

            if (a instanceof RollingFileAppender) 
                {
                ((RollingFileAppender) a).rollOver();
                }
        }
    }
```

This is log4j.properties configuration:

```
log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.File=mylog.log
log4j.appender.logfile.Threshold=ALL
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxBackupIndex=4
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Currently, after `rollOver` I have file with name `mylog.log.1`. How to make file to have name like `mylog_YYYMMDD_HHmmSS.log`?

Comment: May be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/773871/474189

Comment: Why would it do anything else? You haven't set a `FileNamePattern` etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using FileNamePattern, RollingFileAppender in log4j](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324427/using-filenamepattern-rollingfileappender-in-log4j)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DailyRollingFileAppender` instead of `RollingFileAppender`. See this question for details how to configure it: [Setting a log file name to include current date in Log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192456/setting-a-log-file-name-to-include-current-date-in-log4j)

Comment: +1, even better if OP just needs a stock filename, although they stated they wanted HHmmSS as well.

Comment: Despite the name, the `DailyRollingFileAppender` supports the whole range of date/time formatting. It just rolls only once per day by default. Since the OP overrides the rollover, he can get several rollovers per day.

Comment: But DailyRollingFileAppender does't have rollover. I must roll file according special event

Comment: Why do you think "DailyRollingFileAppender does't have rollover"?

Answer (score 0):

Here as per requiment

```
  # Log levels
    log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,CONSOLE,R
    # Appender Configuration
    log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    # Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number
    log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

    log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.R.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
    log4j.appender.R.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=./logs/file_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
    # Layout for Rolling File Appender

    #log4j.appender.R.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH'.log'

    log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d - %c - %p - %m%n
```